# Codeigniter leer valor de sesion desde un controlador en la vista - Porcentaje de progreso

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, progressdialog

tengo el siguiente código en una vista:

```
function getstatus(){
base_url = '<?=base_url()?>';
var percentage;
      $.ajax({
          url: base_url+"teleinforme/getstatus",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data.status);
            if(data.status=="pending"){
              percentage=(data.count/data.size)*100 + '%';
              $('#percentage').text(percentage);
              setTimeout('getstatus()', 1000);
            }
            else{
              alert(data.status);
              $('#percentage').text('100%');        
              $('div#blockUI').hide();
            }
          },
          error: function(data) {
            alert(data.message);
        },
      });
    }
```

Necesito leer el valor de la sessión desde el controlador mientras está ejecutando un for each.  Este es el codigo en el controlador:

```
foreach ($info_reporte as $key => $tupla) {
$arraydata=array("status"=>"pending","count"=>$count ,"size"=>sizeof($info_reporte));
$this->session->set_userdata('downloadstatus', $arraydata);         
$count++;

 // more code
}
```

Esta función es llamada por la función jquery:

```
function getStatus()
{
    echo json_encode($this->session->userdata('downloadstatus'));
}
```

No puedo leer el valor de la session desde la funcion getstatus mientras se setea la sesión dentro del for each.  Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: Hola user2820116, estas en el sitio [es.so], por favor traduce la pregunta al español o migra la pregunta al sitio en inglés [so].

Comment: traducido al español, es mi lengua nativa.